# Sum All VLOOKUP Matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where I am recording what I eat:

[image]

Another where I keep an index of values to lookup

[image]

I tried

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!A2:A11,'Sheet2'!A2:E11,2,FALSE))
```

but that only returned the first match, so then I tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF('Sheet1'!A2:A11,'Sheet2'!A2:A11,'Sheet2'!B2:B11))
```

but that isn't working either.

does anyone have a solution, where I can also multiply the value of the return match by the # of servings in the first sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combine 2 tables into one sheet, `Table 1` housed in Column A & B and `Table 2` housed in Column D & E

In `G2`, "Total Serving Colories" enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},A2:A12)),D2:E12,2,FALSE)*B2:B12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single output of calories through `SUMPRODUCT` then you can use

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B11*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A11,Sheet2!A2:B11,2,0),0))`

1. If you are sure that all entries on Sheet 1 can be located on Sheet 2 then you can drop IFERROR portion like
   `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B11*VLOOKUP(A2:A11,Sheet2!A2:B11,2,0))`.
2. Beware that if a value is not found in Sheet 2 then formula will produce wrong result as `IFERROR` will multiply the serving quantity with 0.

Comment: Tried both, count was off for some reason! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's not super-clear what you're trying to get at.  But defining the "Calories Per Serving" in a range called "cals",

```
+---+---------+-----+--------------------------------+
|   |    A    |  B  |               C                |
+---+---------+-----+--------------------------------+
| 1 | egg     | 3   | =(VLOOKUP(A2,cals,2,FALSE))*B2 |
| 2 | oatmeal | 1.5 | =(VLOOKUP(A3,cals,2,FALSE))*B3 |
| 3 | shrimp  | 2   | =(VLOOKUP(A4,cals,2,FALSE))*B4 |
+---+---------+-----+--------------------------------+
```

Results in:

[image]